# Why does this Python nested for loop produce the output I get?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested

I'm very new to learning python, though I understand the basics of the looping, I am unable to understand the method in which output is arrived at.

In particular, how does the mapping of all three for loops happen to give the desired output, as I finding it impossible to understand the logic to be applied, when I try to write the output on paper without referring to IDE.

Code:

```
n = 4
a = 3
z = 2
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(a):
        for p in range(z):
            print(i, j, p)
```

Output is:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 2 0
0 2 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 2 0
1 2 1
2 0 0
2 0 1
2 1 0
2 1 1
2 2 0
2 2 1
3 0 0
3 0 1
3 1 0
3 1 1
3 2 0
3 2 1
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question. Add your code, what's the current output, what's the expected output as text to the question.

Comment: What aspect of the output, specifically, do you not understand?  Do you not understand the content of specific lines in the output, or do you not understand why there are that many lines, or something else?

Comment: sir it is the output which i do not understand, as to how the mapping of elements happens, when i write it on paper i don't understand how to arrive at this output, without referring to ide...please help....
My actual code was:
n = 4
a = 3
z = 2
for i in range(n):
 
 for j in range(a):

  for p in range(z):

   print(i, j, p)

Comment: it seems like i have been blocked from asking questions for next 3 days, it's sad, but please also let me how to approach to master Python, i am with NO Math, non-engineering background, any tip,

Comment: sir, i have found/learnt that it is the Very first loop's first element which gets executed/iterated, which in turn executes the following inner loop's first element which iterates it's following inner loops first element, this goes on till it iterates all the Elements of all the innermost loop and then the loop go one loop upper to check for the next element for iteration...Am I right here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop iterates four times.

The second loop iterates three times.  However since it is embedded inside the first loop, it actually iterates twelve times (4 * 3.)

The third loop iterates two times.  However since it is embedded inside the first and second loops, it actually iterates twenty-four times (4 * 3 * 2).